# No returned value when calling a class and function containing API call

Tags: python, json, api, class

I am calling Blockchain.INFO's API using a Python libary from GitHub: https://github.com/gowness/pyblockchain

My code can be seen below, when I run the code I get no returned value. I dont have the best knowledge on classes etc but I have read briefly, what is going wrong here?

```
import requests
import urllib
import json
from os.path import expanduser
import configparser

class Wallet: 
    guid        = 'g'
    isAccount   = 0
    isKey       = 0
    password1   = 'x'
    password2   = 'y'
    url         = ''

    def __init__(self, guid = 'g', password1 = 'x', password2 = 'y'):

        if guid.count('-') > 0:
            self.isAccount = 1
            if password1 == '': # wallet guid's contain - 
                raise ValueError('No password with guid.')
        else:
            self.isKey = 1


        self.guid = guid
        self.url = 'https://blockchain.info/merchant/' + guid + '/'

        self.password1 = password1
        self.password2 = password2

    def Call(self, method, data = {}):
        if self.password1 != '':
            data['password'] = self.password1 
        if self.password2 != '':
            data['second_password'] = self.password2

        response = requests.post(self.url + method,params=data)

        json = response.json()
        if 'error' in json:
            raise RuntimeError('ERROR: ' + json['error'])

        return json


    def GetBalance(self):
        response = self.Call('balance')
        return response['balance']

Wallet().GetBalance()
```

Comment: I just fixed your formatting. Can you confirm that is exactly as you expect all appropriate spaces in your code?

Comment: Since I can't make the exact same API call as you, I just ran your code and expectingly I got an exception since I can't hit your URL. However, the code is behaving as expected so far. Can you provide a print of response inside the `GetBalance` method to see what response looks like at that time?

Comment: Im not sure I explained my problem clearly enough. I am trying to run the function GetBalance however when I run the code above I get no output. I know there is a problem with my code somewhere, due to my lack of knowledge of classes and functions. Even If I add a print command in the GetBalance function it wont be run. As if the function where being run it would return the response? Right...? :D

Comment: I'm going to post this as an answer to illustrate. I think your code is working.

Comment: Let me know what you think @Joshua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot run a successful POST call against your URL, I slightly changed your code so that it does not look for 'error' in json, as to see what happens inside your `GetBalance` method.

Now, knowing that by making a call that will fail, the json response will be this:

```
{u'error': u'Unknown Key Format'}
```

So, inside your `GetBalance` method, I simply added a print statement after

```
response = self.Call('balance')
```

And I got a valid json as expected.

All this to say. Try doing this and see what you get:

```
print(Wallet().GetBalance())
```

Based on the response that is coming back, maybe this is indicating that you are not providing the appropriate payload to the server for that POST method you are trying to make?

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck!